# different link and load library paths using cmake

Tags: c++, path, cmake, linker, load

I have two versions of the same library `libabc.so`, I have to link my program to one version, and load another version when it's executed (loader should load another library when executable is run).

I place the two versions in different paths, how can I specify that using cmake?

I hope I have made myself clear, thank you.

Comment: `load another version when it's executed.` - Do you mean that **loader** should load *another* library when executable is run? Unsure that CMake may help in that *in general manner*. But if both libraries files have the **same names** but different locations, then you may adjust RPATH for achive that. BTW, `.o` file is normally an **object file**, not a *library*.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you lots, actually I'm a newbie to c++ and I believe you're right, `loader should load another library when executable is run`, and yes they are of the same name, and `.o` is a typo, thanks!

Comment: Then you probably would want to read about [RPATH handling in CMake](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tsyvarev's comments basically gives the answer, here's a bit more detail.

Say the two versions for link and load are placed in `link_path/libabc.so`  and `load_path/libabc.so`, the `CMakeLists.txt` should be like

```
...
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH load_path;${CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH})  # load path

...
target_link_libraries(xxx link_path/libabc.so)  # link path
```